# Display values of a record dynamically in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

i have a design component that defines which fields i want to fetch and display in the component. The value is stored in `fields` and will look like this, for example: `Name,Sales_Engineer_c`

i have the fields and values in `record` but i don't know how to display them dynamically in my web component.

when i added one of the fields to a `@track` property, i was able to display the value, but i can't do it dynamically.

This is what i have so far:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class RecordProgressBar extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;

    //Design Components
    @api fields;
    @api title;
    @api icon;

    @track record;
    @track error;

    fieldsFormatted = ['Id'];

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: '$fieldsFormatted' })
    wireAccount({data, error}) {
        if(data) {
            this.record = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        }
        else if (error) {
            let message = 'Unknown error';
            if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
                message = error.body.map(e => e.message).join(', ');
            } else if (typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
                message = error.body.message;
            }
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading Object',
                    message,
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
        }
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.fieldsFormatted = (this.fields || 'Id').split(',').map(field => this.objectApiName + '.' + field);
    }
}
```

Comment: `but i can't do it dynamically`  can you elaborate more on it and add markup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For displaying them dynamically, you need to implement array. you can create Array as below:

```
    if (data) {
        this.record = [...Object.keys(data.fields).map(key => {
            return { label: key, value: data.fields[key].value };
        })];
        this.error = undefined;
    }
```

When you give fields like `'Id', 'Name'`, you will get below in `this.record`:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Id",
    "value": "00328000008ZUISAA4"
  },
  {
    "label": "Name",
    "value": "Rose Gonzalez"
  }
]
```

You can display this in HTML as below:

```
<template>

    <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
        <template for:each={record} for:item="field">
            <lightning-layout-item key={field.label} size="6">
                {field.label}: {field.value}
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>

</template>
```

---

**IMPORTANT (This is not necessary but recommended to get proper labels also dynamically):**

However, I would recomment to get the `label`s of fields from `getObjectInfo` and use the labels for displaying dynamically. Import:

```
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
```

Then, assign `fieldsFormatted` in wired service of `getObjectInfo` instead of `connectedCallback`.

```
@api objectName = 'Contact'

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: '$objectName' })
getObjectInfo({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.objectFields = data.fields;
        this.fieldsFormatted = (this.fields || ['Id', 'Name'].join()).split(',').map(field => this.objectApiName + '.' + field);
    }
}
```

Remove `fieldsFormatted` from connectedCallback.

Now, in wired-service to get record, you can do below:

```
if (data) {
        this.record = [...Object.keys(data.fields).map(key => {
            return { label: this.objectFields[key].label, value: data.fields[key].value };
        })];
        this.error = undefined;
    }
```

`this.objectFields[key].label` will get you the correct label defined in object fields definition.

**Also remove `fieldsFormatted = ['Id'];`**

This is because `wireAccount` will invoke even before `getObjectInfo` is invoked and you will get error. Once `fieldsFormatted` is assigned in `getObjectInfo`, the wire-service `getRecord` will be invoked.

Comment: Why do i need to remove the fieldsFormatted from connectedCallback? i use them to get the fields from the design component

Comment: because when fieldsFormatted changes, wireAccount is invoked immediately. But you want to invoke it only after getting `getObjectInfo` which will give you the labels also

Comment: you just have to implement it in `getObjectInfo` (as shown in answer) instead of connectedCallback

Comment: modified answer - its not necessary but recommended to get labels also dynamically

Comment: without the connected callback i received the error `Expected '.' in all qualified names: Id is invalid`

Comment: Also in the `getObjectInfo` you defined `this.objectFields = data.fields;` without defining objectFields anywhere, how is it complied? sorry if its a dumb question, im new to lwc

Comment: You need not define `getObjectInfo`, as you are saying `this.`, it will be attached to class instance. Can you please update your latest code in question (it should actually work)

Comment: Understood the problem. You should remove `fieldsFormatted = ['Id'];` from your code

Comment: Yes! It works!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97591/discussion-between-dana-griff-and-salesforce-sas).